# How to persist one object with many related objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entities `Basket` and `BasketItem`:

```
/**
 * Acme\BasketBundle\Entity\Basket
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\BasketBundle\Repository\BasketRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Basket
{
  /**
   * @var integer $id
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  // ...

  /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BasketItem", mappedBy="order_id",cascade={"all"})
    */
  protected $items;

  // ...

  public function __construct() {
    $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  /**
   * Add item
   *
   * @param BasketItem $item
   */
  public function addItem(BasketItem $item)
  {
    $key = $this->find($item->getProduct()->getId());

    if ($key === false) {
        $this->items->add($item);
    } else {
        $this->items->get($key)->raiseQuantity($item->getQuantity());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Find an item (if present)
   *
   * @param integer $id
   * @return integer
   */
  public function find($id)
  {
    foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $id)
            return $key;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * Acme\BasketBundle\Entity\BasketItem
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_items")
 */
class BasketItem
{
  /**
   * @var integer $id
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  // ...

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Basket", inversedBy="items")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $basket;

  // ...
}
```

---

Now when I create a basket and fill it with items, I have trouble persisting it into the db.

Following doesn't work as expected.

```
$basket = new Basket();
$basket->addItem(new BasketItem($product1, 1));
$basket->addItem(new BasketItem($product2, 2));

$em->persist($basket);
$em->flush();
```

Then I tried following the [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities) more closely:

```
$basket = new Basket();
$basket->addItem(new BasketItem($product1, 1));
$basket->addItem(new BasketItem($product2, 2));

$em->persist($basket);
foreach ($basket->getItems() as $item) {
    $em->persist($item);
}
$em->flush();
```

That didn't work as expected neither.

In both cases all the data gets saved to the database **but** the basket items are not related to the basket, i.e. `order_id` of the `BasketItem` entity is `NULL`.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong, please? Please note I'm new to Doctrine. Thanks!

---

---

---

**EDIT**:

I'm really confused already. Here's my simplified test:

```
<?php

namespace Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity\Basket
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Amsel\BasketBundle\Repository\BasketRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 */
class Basket
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $items
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BasketItem", mappedBy="basket", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $items;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add item
     *
     * @param BasketItem $item
     */
    public function addItem(BasketItem $item)
    {
        $this->items->add($item);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity\BasketItem
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Amsel\BasketBundle\Repository\BasketItemRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_items")
 */
class BasketItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Basket $basket
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Basket", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $basket;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set basket
     *
     * @param Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity\Basket $basket
     */
    public function setBasket(\Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity\Basket $basket)
    {
        $this->basket = $basket;
    }

    /**
     * Get basket
     *
     * @return Amsel\BasketBundle\Entity\Basket 
     */
    public function getBasket()
    {
        return $this->basket;
    }
}
```

```
public function testAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $basket = new Basket();
    $basket->addItem(new BasketItem());
    $basket->addItem(new BasketItem());

    $em->persist($basket);

    try {
        $em->flush();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('ERROR: '.$e->getMessage());
    }        
    die ('end');
}
```

But still - the order items (`BasketItem`) get stored but are *not* linked to the order (`Basket`).

Comment: Can you post the contents of your addItem function? Does it internally call $this->items->add($item); ? The rest looks okay..

Comment: @Kees Schepers, thanks for your reply! I've added the method `addItem` (and `find`). If the rest is ok, I'm really lost - any more ideas what could I try?

Comment: I had some simular problem a while ago, do you specify your field $order_id in your BasketItem class maybe? Cause this can cause these problems. If you doubt you can post your whole basketitem entity class. My friend has blogged about this with me: http://pietervogelaar.nl/doctrine-2-use-foreign-key-as-field-in-dql/

Comment: @Kees Schepers, no, I store just `$product_id` (not an ORM field) so that I am able to easily serialize the basket (via `__sleep`).

Comment: @Kees Schepers, I've editted in a simplified example that is 1:1 what I do. I cannot understand why it still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the system correctly, I also have to - because it is a bidirectional relation - manually assign the parent `Basket` entity to every `BasketItem` entity.

```
public function testAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $basket = new Basket();

    $bi1 = new BasketItem();
    $bi1->setBasket($basket);

    $bi2 = new BasketItem();
    $bi2->setBasket($basket);

    $basket->addItem($bi1);
    $basket->addItem($bi2);

    $em->persist($basket);

    try {
        $em->flush();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('ERROR: '.$e->getMessage());
    }        
    die ('end');
}
```

It works fine like this but if I'm going in a wrong way, please correct me.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at my question!

Comment: Yhis is correct. However you should make it easy on yourself and associate the basket to the item _inside_ the 'addItem' method of the basket entity. Kees Schepers pointed this out above. This is the correct thing to do (as it means you can never 'forget' to do it in one of your controllers)

Comment: @kissmyface, yeah, that's how I did it (the above is just the first version I got working). If I understood him correctly, Kees just asked if I add it to the items collection. And that's what I've thought is enough...

Answer (score 3):

Your annotation mapping is wrong in your Basket entity : the "mappedBy" attribute must refers to an entity field, not to a database column.

```
/**  
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BasketItem", mappedBy="basket",cascade={"all"})  
 */  
 protected $items;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified that but it still doesn't work - `order_id` column stays `NULL`.

Comment: What does BasketItem constructor ? Can you post its content ?

Comment: I've editted in a simplified example that is 1:1 what I do. I cannot understand why it still fails.

Comment: I think I've found the solution, posted in my answer. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I`m new at Symfony and Doctrine but this is weird. I tought that it should work both ways but seems that u have to set Basket on BasketItem

```
$bi->setBasket($basket);
```

if u want to make it working both ways e.g:

```
$basket->addItem($bi);
```

u have to modify your addItem method and removeItem method

```
/**
 * Add item
 *
 * @param BasketItem $item
 */
public function addItem(BasketItem $item)
{
    $item->setBasket($this);
    $this->items->add($item);
}

/**
 * Remove item
 *
 * @param BasketItem $item
 */
public function removeItem(BasketItem $item)
{
    $item->setBasket(null);
    $this->items->removeElement($item);
}
```

[EDIT] look this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association